# Querying GraphQL with PowerShell

Tags: powershell, curl, graphql, cloudflare

So I've been trying to query GraphQL from PowerShell. Everything looks perfect in a cmd, but I cannot make it work in PS, see, I have this code so far:

```
$oAuth2TokenUrl = "https://api.cloudflare.com/client/v4/zones/0000/analytics/dashboard"
$accessKey = '1111' 

$Cloudflare_Oauth_Header = @{
    "Authorization" = "Bearer $accessKey";
}

$query = @'
{ "query": "query { viewer {
zones(filter: {zoneTag: 0000}) {
  httpRequests1mGroups(orderBy: [datetimeMinute_ASC], limit: 1000, filter: {datetime_geq: "2019-09-08T20:00:00Z", datetime_lt: "2019-09-08T20:02:00Z"}) {
    dimensions {datetimeMinute}
    sum {
      browserMap {
        pageViews
        uaBrowserFamily
      }
      bytes
      cachedBytes
      cachedRequests
      contentTypeMap {
        bytes
        requests
        edgeResponseContentTypeName
      }
      clientSSLMap {
        requests
        clientSSLProtocol
      }
      countryMap {
        bytes
        requests
        threats
        clientCountryName
      }
      encryptedBytes
      encryptedRequests
      ipClassMap {
        requests
        ipType
      }
      pageViews
      requests
      responseStatusMap {
        requests
        edgeResponseStatus
      }
      threats
      threatPathingMap {
        requests
        threatPathingName
      }
    }
    uniq {
      uniques
    }
  }
}
  } }" }
'@


$Cloudflare_zone = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Headers $Cloudflare_Oauth_Header -ContentType "application/json; charset=utf-8" -Uri $oAuth2TokenUrl -Body $query
```

And I keep getting the error `Invoke-RestMethod : The remote server returned an error: (501) Not Implemented.` 
But if I curl in cmd it returns what is expected and no error is shown.

Please let me know if you need more details.

Comment: Did you solve it ? Look at eg https://www.reddit.com/r/PowerShell/comments/b9jasa/query_graphql_with_powershell/

Answer (score 2):

I have a GraphQL module for PowerShell with a single function (Invoke-GraphQLQuery that may help you here). Link: https://github.com/anthonyg-1/PSGraphQL

But I definitely agree that you should start with a much smaller query. Check out some of the examples in my readme or run Get-Help Invoke-GraphQLQuery for more.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest getting a simple query to work first, and then expanding it to be more complex. Also, be sure to use `-ContentType "application/json"` which some GraphQL servers require. The switch `-UseBasicParsing` can also help avert error but probably isn't the issue here. Lastly, you might also need a trailing slash in the URL: E.g., http://127.0.0.1:8080/graphql/.

This thread might also help:
https://www.reddit.com/r/PowerShell/comments/b9jasa/query_graphql_with_powershell/